# How to evaluate an expression stored in a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to do this....

```
dim mVar as String = ""
dim mVar1 as double
dim mVar2 as double

mvar= " mVar1> mVar2 "

if mvar Then
.
.
.
End IF
```

Is it supported in vb.net?

If yes then how?

`mvar` will have different conditions as pert my requirement.

Comment: There are ways, but they're quite cumbersome. Where is this string coming from?

Comment: string is coming from my code..and it'll carry different values depending on my code.

Comment: So, it's not being provided by a user. Any reason it can't be a `Func(Of Double,Double,Boolean)` instead? (Or even just a `Func(Of Boolean)` maybe)

Comment: i wanted to know sir....can we pass a condition in a variable(any kind) for further checking.

Comment: If you want... I can elaborate the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `String`, you can use a `Delegate` for your conditions.

**Example:**

```
Dim var1 As Double = 14.03
Dim var2 As Double = 13.99

Dim biggerThan = Function(a As Double, b As Double) a > b
Dim areEqual = Function(a As Double, b As Double) a = b

If biggerThan(var1, var2) Then
    Console.WriteLine("var1 > var2")
Else If areEqual(var1, var2) Then
    Console.WriteLine("var1 = var2")
End If

var1 = 13.99

If biggerThan(var1, var2) Then
    Console.WriteLine("var1 > var2")
Else If areEqual(var1, var2) Then
    Console.WriteLine("var1 = var2")
End If
```

**Output:**

```
var1 > var2
var1 = var2
```

---

If you really want or have to use strings, take a look at the [Flee](https://flee.codeplex.com/) library.

**Example:**

```
Dim context = New ExpressionContext()
context.Variables("var1") = 14.03
context.Variables("var2") = 13.99

Dim result = context.CompileGeneric(Of Boolean)("var1 > var2").Evaluate()
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

**Output:**

```
True
```